# How to show date in diffrent way in GridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, devexpress

I'd like to change [DisplayFormat](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.DisplayFormat.property) in my [grid](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3455/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid) from

```
"MM/dd/yyyy"
```

to

```
"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: Could you show how you are making the attempt?

Comment: See following posting?

Comment: @Crowcoder I am using DevExpress Designer the GUI for DevExpress.XtraEditor.XtraUserControl and editing DisplayFormat property.

Comment: Yes I see answers but problem is not in how to display date in console but how to display in GUI on [GridView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.class).

Comment: What does the underlying source data look like the grid is bound to? Is it a strong typed `DateTime` value or a string?

Comment: It is not the string it is DateTime.

Comment: There isn't enough information to help, the problem isn't with what you've shown so one can only guess. You need a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show **all** relevant code. How do you set the properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier for me to answer my question than isolated working code in my complex program. So this is my hack that works inside my program:

```
private void GridView_CustomDrawEvent(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Column.FieldName == "CreationDate")
    {
        string date = ((DateTime) view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "CreationDate"));
        string displayDate = date.ToShortDateString() + " " time.ToLongTimeString();
        e.DisplayText = displayDate;
    }
}
```

I catch my [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) object in [CustomDrawCell](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomDrawCell.event) event and I am translating it to string using two standard methods [DateTime.ToShortDateString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [DateTime.ToLongTimeString().](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolongtimestring?view=netframework-4.7.2) Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this (example):

```
static void Main()
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;             // Use current time.
    string format = "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss";    // Use this format.
    Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format)); // Write to console.
}
```

So when inserting your data in the GridView, you convert it to a string with the selected format.

Here's the link for multiple date format and how to use them: https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Answer (score 0):

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkPUX.png)

Set Display format

```
dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McxS0.png)